# Referencing user controls that are contained within the same VB.NET project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, user-controls

I do apologize if this post is a duplicate, but I haven't found anything similar when I searched.

I'm fairly new to VB.NET and I'm currently playing around with user controls, figuring out good programming practices. As far as I understand, to create and use a UserControl, I need to create a project with the UserControl in it, then build the project and use that DLL (add it to Toolbox or otherwise).

My question is this: Is there a way a have a project (a Form with a bunch of things on it) that contains a UserControl written in a *.vb file inside *that same Project*? If you do that, the DLL (in my case) never gets produced, possibly because the UserControl is never used and building it is simply omitted. Is it perhaps a bad practice to do that altogether? It simply makes sense to me to keep a UserControl as a part of the Project that uniquely uses it. Is there a reason not to do that?

Thanks in advance! = )

**SOLUTION:**
Visual Studio does *not* automatically include your own controls to the toolbox by default! In order to change that, go to Tools>Options>Windows Form Designer>General and set `AutoToolboxPopulate` to `True`. When you build your project next time, your new Control will appear in your Toolbox.

Comment: next time, you can answer your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a perfectly valid design decision to include a UserControl in a WinForm or WPF project that uses it.  If you do this then VS will not create a DLL for the UserControl; instead the UserControl will be built into the assembly your project is producing.

If you did want to reuse a UserControl in multiple projects then you would want to create separate project that generates a DLL that can be reused.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way then to add that control to a Toolbox or a similar way to be able to drag-and-drop my UserControl into a Form? Maybe I'm just not great at navigating Visual Studio yet (I come from Unix programming mainly)?

Comment: @Phonon The UserControl should be automatically added to the Toolbox of the project it's part of when you have a form designer open.  You should see it in a tab named Components.  At least I do, but then I'm using VS 2008 (I'd think this would be true in VS 2010).